# Why $F^{+}$ is a monopresheaf?

Tags: sheaf-theory, topos-theory

I'm having difficult in proving that  given a site $(C, J)$, then $F^{+}(c) = colim_{R \in J(c)} R $ is a monopresheaf, in the sense that there exists at most one lifting of $R \longrightarrow F^{+}$ to $h_U$ for $R \in J(U)$. Furthermore considering topological spaces, is there an interpretration of the functor ${+}$ viewing $F$ as an étale space? Note that the functor ${++}$ from presheaves over a topological space can be defined picking the sections of the étale space $\coprod_{x \in X} F_x$.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There is no hope of interpreting $(-)^+$ in terms of espace étalé, because those things are already sheaves...

Comment: @ZhenLin Yes, the sections of an étale space is a sheaf, but picking a subfunctor of the sections instead, or something similar would'nt provide an interpretation?

Comment: Well, you can see $F^+$ as a subpresheaf $F^{++}$, which is the sheaf of sections of the associated espace étalé.